# Obtaining data from my TP-Link router programmatically

Tags: android, cgi, router, legacy-code

I'm trying to design an app that can communicate with my router programmatically using the same endpoints as the web interface (there's [a demo](http://uk.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/TD-W8980/index.htm) on TP-Link's website). My router is a TP-Link TD-W8980, if that matters.

The format appears to be very difficult to decipher. Here is a request which obtains the data for the status part of my app. This can obtain a valid response from the router but I'm not sure why!

**I'm especially confused by the `#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]` part of the response. It's the only part I haven't managed to work out but I think I recall reading it's to do with the stack?!?**

```
[SYS_MODE#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]0,1
mode
[LAN_HOST_CFG#1,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]1,1
DNSServers
[WAN_DSL_INTF_CFG#1,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]2,8
upstreamCurrRate
downstreamCurrRate
upstreamMaxRate
downstreamMaxRate
upstreamNoiseMargin
downstreamNoiseMargin
upstreamAttenuation
downstreamAttenuation
[IGD_DEV_INFO#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]3,3
softwareVersion
hardwareVersion
upTime
[LAN_IP_INTF#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]4,2
IPInterfaceIPAddress
X_TPLINK_MACAddress
[LAN_HOST_ENTRY#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]5,4
leaseTimeRemaining
MACAddress
hostName
IPAddress
[WAN_PPP_CONN#0,0,0,0,0,0#0,0,0,0,0,0]6,4
enable
connectionStatus
externalIPAddress
DNSServers
```

If it helps, the names in capitals (e.g. `SYS_MODE`) is the name of the section. The number after the `]` is a counter stating the section number (sections can be in any order). The final number following the `,` is the number of parameters that follow in this section.

There are also request types for each section. In the example above, the URL is `http://192.168.1.1/cgi?1&1&1&1&5&5&5`. As you can see the two main request types are `1` and `5`.

Here is an example response from the server. As you can see, some of the sections can be returned more than once, which makes the first number of the six zeros increment each time.

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0]0
mode=DSL
[1,0,0,0,0,0]1
DNSServers=x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x
[1,0,0,0,0,0]2
upstreamCurrRate=928
downstreamCurrRate=3072
upstreamMaxRate=1068
downstreamMaxRate=3104
upstreamNoiseMargin=60
downstreamNoiseMargin=57
upstreamAttenuation=295
downstreamAttenuation=546
[0,0,0,0,0,0]3
softwareVersion=0.6.0 1.3 v000e.0 Build 131012 Rel.51720n
hardwareVersion=TD-W8980 v1 00000000
upTime=x
[1,1,0,0,0,0]4
IPInterfaceIPAddress=192.168.1.1
X_TPLINK_MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[1,0,0,0,0,0]5
leaseTimeRemaining=-1
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
hostName=X
IPAddress=192.168.1.2
[2,0,0,0,0,0]5
leaseTimeRemaining=-1
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
hostName=X
IPAddress=192.168.1.4
[3,0,0,0,0,0]5
leaseTimeRemaining=-1
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
hostName=X
IPAddress=192.168.1.11
[4,0,0,0,0,0]5
leaseTimeRemaining=-1
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
hostName=X
IPAddress=192.168.1.5
[1,2,1,0,0,0]6
enable=1
connectionStatus=Connected
externalIPAddress=x.x.x.x
DNSServers=x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x
[2,1,1,0,0,0]6
enable=0
connectionStatus=Unconfigured
externalIPAddress=0.0.0.0
DNSServers=0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0
[3,1,1,0,0,0]6
enable=0
connectionStatus=Unconfigured
externalIPAddress=0.0.0.0
DNSServers=0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0
[error]0
```

I would appreciate any explanation of this format and if it appears anywhere else on the web. I've never seen such a system before!

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do the same but with another tplink model, Could you do it successfully?

Comment: @Reidel, I did indeed - had to just go with some of the things like the request type id (usually 1 or 5). In the end I switched to OpenWrt though as it is much more customisable and common.

Comment: Can you address me a place where I can read more about this, I have not found nothing understandable

Comment: can you share its source code for helping other people?